# create inner join between field not mapped with a field in database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

How do I create a relationship between fields  DecodePersonnelID and PersonnelID Field

```
public partial class MyUser
{
public int UsersID { get; set; }
public string PersonnelID { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public int DecodePersonnelID
{
    get { return DecodeMD5PersonnelID(PersonnelID); }
    set { PersonnelID = EncodeMD5(value.ToString() ); }
}
public string UsersName { get; set; }
}
public partial class Personnel
{
public int PersonnelID { get; set; }
public string FirstNameFa { get; set; }
public string LastNameFa { get; set; }
public bool Gender { get; set; }
}


RAYANContext db=new RAYANContext();
        var query = (from m in db.MyUsers
                     join p in db.Personnels on m.DecodePersonnelID equals p.PersonnelID
                     select new
                     {
                         m.UsersName,
                         p.FirstNameEn
                     }).ToList();
```

Error:The specified type member 'DecodePersonnelID' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the ID encoded in one table and not in the other?  Wouldn't it make more sense (both for simplicity and security) to encode them in both places?